# cakephp authentication by user id

Tags: cakephp, authentication

Is it possible in CakePHP 1.3 to login a user by indicating the user's id in the **users** table?

Now, to do a "manual" login, I do this (which works):

```
$this->data['User']['username'] = username;
$this->data['User']['password'] = password;
$this->Auth->login($this->data);
```

I would like to be able to indicate the specific user, for example adding **$this->data['User']['user_id']** before the login() function. (I've tried that but it doesn't work).

The reason I want to do this is because in the **users** table there are different users records of users who have the same **username** and **password**. It seems odd but in my case makes sense, since one same user may create several accounts for different reasons, and he may choose the same username/password.

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

**EDIT:**

I'm going to give a specific example of what I'm trying to do, maybe it helps to bring some ideas.

Say I have this 2 records in the users table (fields are **user_id** / **username** / **password** / **account_id**):

- Record 1: 1 / johndoe / password1 / 10
- Record 2: 2 / johndoe / password1 / 15

So this 2 records have same username and password, but different user_id and account_id. When the login is processed, I know what **account_id** the user has chosen. So I want to log in the corresponding user. So if the user chooses account 15, then logs is, I should be logging in the user with id 2.

However, the way cake's login works, it always retrieves the first record that matches username / password. In this example, cake would be logging in the user with id 1.

Is there any way I can do what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't sound like a very good idea to me, but if you really want/must do it that way, then have a look at [`AuthComponent::userScope`](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Core-Components/Authentication.html#userscope). You can use it to define additional conditions for authentication lookups, for example:

```
$this->Auth->userScope = array('User.account_id' => 15);
```

That way authentication would only be successful when username and password match and the users `account_id` is `15`, ie the resulting query would look something like this

```
User.username = 'abc' AND User.password = 'xyz' AND User.account_id = 15
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. The thing is that I'm not sure this is what I need, because this allows to include conditions once a record that matches username/password is found. However, I need something that allows me to choose the record by its user_id. I see that I probably need a custom login function. I'm going to update my question to explain in more detail what I'm trying to do

Comment: This still sounds like what you are looking for. The conditions defined in `userScope` are being used in the same query that checks the username and password, which means you would only retreive the user where `account_id = 15` (I've changed the column name in the example). So by defining such a condition you would effectively choose a specific user (assuming the account_id/username combination is unique).

Comment: ok thanks! just to be sure, where should I place the line `$this->Auth->userScope = array('User.account_id' => $current_account_id);`? Does it need to be in the beforeFilter()? Or can I call it from a different action as long as it's before the login() action is called?

Comment: You can put it wherever you want as long as its being invoked before your call to `AuthComponent::login()`.